# executing php script in background initiated from a browser

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am writing a php script to send mails to all the email addresses in a particular mailing list. The mails might run into thousands and the entire script can take even hours to execute. What I want is the once the user enter the mail details, body, subject etc and hits a button/link, the php script runs in background and the user is redirected to some page as soon as he hits the button/link.

In short the php script should be initiated from the browser but should run on the server even if the browser is closed.

Alternatively if a progress bar can be shown on redirected page using AJAX/Javascript but the php script should continue executing even if the browser is closed.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is the **wrong tool for the job**. Set up a mailing list on a e-mail server (perhaps the same server), and from the browser hand the data to PHP via ajax, which should then send the e-mail (**only once**) to the mailing list.

The e-mail software will take care of sending a copy to every subscriber of the mailing list.

This is one of the **most efficient** ways of doing it.

Some links which may help you do more research:

- http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#lists
- http://www.courier-mta.org/couriermlm.html

Remember though, this has **nothing** to do with programming, and you should ask for help on some other stack exchange site (like [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

To get both the script to continue and having it giving it status even though the user refresh this is a bit of work.

The super easy approach is to drop the the second part.
If you just need a action to be executed server side you could have a XHR (aka ajax) and give the progression with a long polling approach.

If you want the process to be independent from the user connection you need to spawn a new PHP instance each time. and then find a way to get its output to the user.
You could store the output into a redis for example.

Comment: so if i drop showing the progression bar and just want that script to complete execution even if the browser is closed, what needs to be done ??

Comment: If you go this way, when you'll hit the 1000 mark, you'll come back to my answer anyway. Basically, any way you'd try to use a software (here: PHP) in a way it has not been intented to be used will **at some point** kill your server ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is the following:

On click of the button call your processing script. The processing script should then handle the request by using [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ignore-user-abort.php) to prevent the script from stopping once the browser moves on and then redirecting the broser with a [header('Location: success.html');](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php)

```
<?php
  ignore_user_abort(true);
  header('Location: success.html');
  echo 'Making sure the header gets flushed';
  flush();

  //Send out the mails
?>
```

However you will need to make sure there is no output buffering active for the script. If you're using some compression modules or anything those might wait for the whole process to finish before delivering the content and therefore freezing the whole thing. Best is to disable any output buffering for the script url.

This is similar to how you would create a deamon in PHP.